# Javascript prototype Methods inside object

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I'm trying to create an Object containing other Objects and functions, in a prototype, the relevant part is the UI prototype;

```
var fChat = function() {
    this.debug = true;
};

fChat.prototype = {
    constructor: fChat,
    Log: function(str){
        if(this.debug){
            console.log(str);
        }
    },
    UI: {
        Login: {
            Show: function(){
                this.Log("UI.Login.Show()");
            }
        }           
    }
};

var fChatInstance = new fChat();
fChatInstance.UI.Login.Show();
```

When i call `fChatInstance.UI.Login.Show()` It give me an error:
`Uncaught TypeError: this.Log is not a function`

Is that because by using `this` is on another scope?
Usually i do `var self = this;`at the start of a prototype, but i don't know how I can do that by using an Object prototype.

Comment: `this` is the object `{ Show: function() { /*...*/ } }`. You can figure that out by debugging within `Show` and checking `this` or by doing `console.log(this);` within `Show`

Comment: This is a bit of a strange pattern. So each `fChat` has it's own singletons of `Log`, `UI`? Seems like all of that stuff should be abstracted out into their own unit-of-work "classes"

Comment: @RGraham it is the first time i use prototypes and "classes", so i can do it in a wrong way. Anyway i initialize only one instance of fChat.

Comment: I agree with @RGraham that it's better to split this "class" up into multiple classes. For example, create a `Login` class and then pass in a `Logger` class instance in the constructor. Right now that `fChat` class has [multiple responsibilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: Checkout [**You Don't Know JS: *this* & Object Prototypes**](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md) for some good information about this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The problem is the javascript dynamic binding of this, to fix it you can set "this" to the object by using bind function. Change the fchat function refactor it like this:

```
var fChat = function() {
  this.debug = true;
  this.UI.Login.Show =  this.UI.Login.Show.bind(this);
  this.Log =  this.Log.bind(this);
};
```